# How to make a value = any value other than another value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume hashtag can be in other positions besides between 2 and 3.

```py
hashtag = '#'

game = '12#3'

if "all values of game, besides hashtag are 1, 2 or 3":
    print(‘yes’)
else:
    print(‘no’)
```

How do I write the if-statement (now written as pseudo-code between quotes) in Python?

Comment: I dont want the if function to consider the hashtag

Comment: Please, provide a few examples then. Right now it is unclear to me

Comment: It seems to me that you question can also be rephrased as "all values of game are 1, 2, 3 or hashtag'? Is that right? Some examples would be helpful to understand what you mean!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
hashtag = '#'
game = '12#3'

if hashtag not in game:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do the following:

```py
hashtag = '#'
game = '12#3'

if (v in game) and (v != hashtag):
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: I thought OP was trying to check if some value `v` is equal to characters any other than hashtag. Maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your task can be also phrased as this:
Print 'yes' if `game` contains only characters of the set `{1,2,3,#}`.

```py
allowed_characters = {'1', '2', '#', '3'}
game = '12#3'
check = all(x in allowed_characters for x in game)
```

The above code snippet will store `True` in check if that condition is fulfilled.

More examples:

```
>>> game = '1#23'
>>> all(x in allowed_characters for x in game)
True
>>> game = 'a123'
>>> all(x in allowed_characters for x in game)
False
```